# summernote is showing html code after retrieving from Mysql DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, summernote

Im using summernote wyswyg editor, I write some content in the editor then i save it in the Mysql DB, now when i retrieve the content from DB using php and echo it on summernote, the editor shows the html code instead of the formatted content as we see on wyswyg, please give me some solution for this. 
My code:

```html
 <textarea id="summernote" class="form-control" placeholder="Article" name="article_content"><?php echo $article_content; ?></textarea>
```

```js
    <script src="summernote-0.7.0-dist/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#summernote').summernote({
  height: "300px"
 });
});
var postForm = function() {
 var content = $('textarea[name="article_content"]').html($('#summernote').code());
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideea is good, the problem is how you take the data.

You should use `$('#summernote').summernote('code')` to take the data, then echo in a div/text area